# Will iTunes Match organize my local files?

Tags: macos, itunes, windows, itunes-match

Today I organized some of my songs/albums on my Macbook Pro while I was at work. My main/local files are on my PC at home which is also connected to Match.

After organizing songs in the cloud, will that sync down to my local PC files and organize them there?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you organize in iCloud this will organize in iCloud in your PC. This is normal to do, but for you want that this organize the local files in the pc you need to go to the preferences and enable the option to keep your directory organized! :)

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I have that option enabled already. I don't think that's quite the answer I'm looking for. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... Since my PC was the first one to enable and upload songs to iTunes Match I had to organize them on my PC myself. Even though I had made changes in the cloud on my Macbook, those changes weren't transferring down to my PC. Hopefully this helps someone else.